# Busqueda Binaria Java

Tags: java, busqueda, matriz

**Necesito aplicar a una funcion recursiva, busqueda binaria, la funcion es la siguiente:**

```
public static int returnPos(int[][]m, int x, int y, int n){
        if(x == m.length){
            return -1;
        }else{
            if(m[x][y] == n){     
                return 1;
            }
            if(y == m[x].length -1){            
                y=0;
                x++;
            }
            else{
                y++;
            }
           return 1 + returnPos(m, x, y, n);                
        }
    }
```

*La funcion busca un numero en la matriz recursivamente y retorna la posicion del mismo.*
**Recibe por parametro la siguiente matriz:**

```
int[][] matriz = {{2, 3, 5, 6, 6}, 
                  {2, 4, 5, 7, 8},  
                  {5 ,5, 6, 7, 8},
                  {5 ,7, 7, 8, 9}};
```

**y x = 0, y = 0, n = numero a buscar.**
Si la observan detenidamente se darán cuenta que desde la posición [0][0], la matriz va en orden **ascendiente** hacia la derecha, abajo y en diagonal.

Mi pregunta es, de que manera podría recorrer la matriz con búsqueda binaria, pensé hacerlo con la diagonal principal ya que esta ordenada de manera **ascendente**, pero no se de que manera podría aplicar eso en el código.

Comment: Un array bidimensional es simplemente el conjunto de múltiples arrays unidimensional. Así que solo debes aplicar la búsqueda binaria a cada fila del *array 2D*. La forma más sencilla sería crear un método en la cual reciba como parámetro un *array* unidimensional y luego ejecutar el método para cada fila de la matriz. Ya que la manera como has diseñado el método `returnPos` no es el apropiado para una búsqueda binaria.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a aplicar!

Comment: El encabezado del método podría quedar así: `int returnPos(int[] m, int n)` y luego invocas el método de esta forma: `returnPos(matriz[0], 10);` En este ejemplo, busca el número `10` en la primera fila del *array bidimensional* y debería de retornar la posición donde se encontró el dato o `-1` si es que no lo encuentra. La razón de esto es porque la búsqueda binaria se aplica expresamente para *array unidimensional*.

Comment: Independientemente de las acotaciones realizadas por @MrDave1999, veo una inconsistencia en tu problema. El `array` de elementos tiene elementos repetidos, por lo tanto si buscas, por ejemplo, el número 6, el mismo se encuentra en las posiciones `[0,3], [0,4] y [2,2]`. ¿Cuál valor de los anteriores debe devolver tu función y porqué?

Comment: Claro, quizas devolver la posicion del primer valor encontrado, ya que como debo optimizar la funcion returnPos(), y la misma retorna el primer encontrado.